# How to write a member function with variadic parameters as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Is it possible to write template function in C++14 like below

Here is the sample  https://godbolt.org/z/9gRk-t

```
// pseudo code

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R(T::*mf)(Args...), Args&&... args) 
{
  return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

So, for a test class

```
struct Test 
{
  int Func(){return 1;};
  bool Func(bool){return true;};  // overload

  void FuncInt(int){};
};
```

The template coudl work for the use case below (but it failed)

```
int main()
{
  Test test;

  // for overload case
  auto a = Call<int()>(test, &Test::Func);
  auto b = Call<bool(bool)>(test, &Test::Func, true);

  // for non-overload case
  Call(test, &Test::FuncInt, 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Herer the erro info.

```
#1 with x64 msvc v19.24
example.cpp
<source>(23): error C2672: 'Call': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(23): error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'decltype(auto) Call(T &,R (__cdecl T::* )(Args...),Args &&...)'
<source>(5): note: see declaration of 'Call'
<source>(24): error C2672: 'Call': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(24): error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'decltype(auto) Call(T &,R (__cdecl T::* )(Args...),Args &&...)'
<source>(5): note: see declaration of 'Call'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: Syntax errors in `Test` member definitions: redundant semicolons after method definitions, missing semicolon after `return` statements and struct's closing brace.

Comment: Notice there is [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) in C++17

Comment: @Jarod42 Although you can't directly pass a pointer to overloaded member function to `std::invoke`.

Comment: @aschepler: `std::invoke(static_cast<bool (Test::*)(bool)>(&Test::Func), test, true);` or `std::invoke([](Test& test, auto... args){ return test.Func(args...);}, test, true);`.

Comment: @Jarod Which is why I made sure to type "directly" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your declaration of `Call`:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R(T::*mf)(Args...), Args&&... args);
```

the function template takes (or might try to deduce) two or more template arguments: the first is `T`, the second is `R`, and the rest are `Args`. So giving a single function type as the first template argument as in `Call<int()>` and `Call<bool(bool)>` is wrong. The correct way to call it would be

```
auto a = Call<Test, int>(test, &Test::Func);
auto b = Call<Test, bool, bool>(test, &Test::Func, true);
```

Another issue is that if you want the template arguments deduced, as in the non-overloaded case, since the `Args` pack appears twice, it will only work if the lists deduced from the member function and from the trailing arguments are exactly the same:

```
int n = 3;
Call(test, &Test::FuncInt, n); // error!
// Args... is deduced to `int` from `&Test::FuncInt`, but deduced to `int&`
// from `n` since it's an lvalue matching a forwarding reference parameter.
```

If you prefer the function type syntax, you could use the solution of [@foo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60898806/459640):

```
template <typename FuncT, typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, FuncT T::*mf, Args&&... args)
    noexcept(noexcept((obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
{
    return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// main() exactly as in question, including Call<int()> and Call<bool(bool)>.
```

`FuncT T::*mf` is the syntax for declaring a pointer-to-member, which is often used to point to a data member, but also works to point to a function if the type `FuncT` is a function type. (I've added the `constexpr` and conditional exception specifier to make it more generic.)

This also solves an issue with the original, which can't be used to invoke a member function which is `const` or which has a ref-qualifier, since this creates a different function type:

```
class Test2 {
public:
    int get() const;
    void set() &;
};

void driver_Test2() {
    Test2 test;

    // Error with original Call:
    // Type of &Test2::get is "int (Test2::*)() const",
    // which cannot match "R (Test2::*)(Args...)"
    int a = Call(test, &Test2::get);

    // Error with original Call:
    // Type of &Test2::set is "void (Test2::*)(int) &",
    // which cannot match "R (Test2::*)(Args...)"
    Call(test, &Test2::set, 1);
}
```

But with the new `Call` definition, `driver_Test2` is fine, since any non-static member function can match `FuncT T::*`. If we wanted to supply a template argument to the calls in `driver_Test2`, maybe because the member functions are overloaded, that would look like `Call<int() const>` and `Call<void() &>`.

Answer (score 3):

Issue with

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R(T::*mf)(Args...), Args&&... args)
```

is that `Args` is deduced twice and should be identical.

There are several ways to fix that issue:

- Add extra template parameter:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, typename ... Ts>
  decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R(T::*mf)(Args...), Ts&&... args)
  {
      return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
  }
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/uzA6Hf)
- or make parameter non deducible (I use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) from C++20 but can trivially be reimplemented in previous version):

  ```
  template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R(T::*mf)(Args...), std::type_identity_t<Args>... args)
  {
      return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ```
- or change completely signature:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename M, typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, M mf, Args&&... args)
  {
      return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ```

  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/JBwSbJ)

Comment: The 1st solution doesn't work for overloaded case. [godbolt.org/z/joUTQw](https://godbolt.org/z/joUTQw)

The 3rd solution doesn't work for all case. [godbolt.org/z/D8g-Kq](https://godbolt.org/z/D8g-Kq)

I call them in a wrong way?

Comment: @foo: The way you select overload is wrong, fixed typo in last solution. Demo added

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. It is quietly like std::men_fn.

Here it is the code below and sample https://godbolt.org/z/NoWPV_

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Proxy
{
    template<typename R, typename ...Args>
    decltype(auto) Call(T& obj, R T::*mf, Args&&... args)
    {
        return (obj.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct Test 
{
  int Func(){return 1;};
  bool Func(bool){return true;};  // overload

  void FuncInt(int){};
};

int main()
{
  Test test;
  Proxy<Test> proxy;

  // for overload case
  auto a = proxy.Call<int()>(test, &Test::Func);
  auto b = proxy.Call<bool(bool)>(test, &Test::Func, true);

  // for non-overload case
  proxy.Call(test, &Test::FuncInt, 1);

  return 0;
}
```